# how to get thumbnail from audio url in android using glide

Tags: android, url, audio

Trying to load audio thumbnail  from url with glide but  is not working

```
Glide
                .with(this)
                .load("http://api.boleiachain.com/upload/musictest.mp3")
                .apply(options)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading)
                .into(civ_image);
```

and I have tried this

```
public  Bitmap coverpicture(String path) {

        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(path, new HashMap<String, String>());
        try {
            final byte[] coverImage = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
             bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(coverImage, 0, coverImage.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;

    }

Glide
                .with(this)
                .load(coverpicture("http://api.boleiachain.com/upload/musictest.mp3"))
                .apply(options)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading)
                .into(civ_image);
```

it works but with delay, which is not good practice in recyclerView adapter

Comment: metwork calls will take time no matter what,

Answer (score 1):

You can cache the bitmaps and check cache exists before calling coverPicture method

```
  ....load(getCoverpicture("http://api.boleiachain.com/upload/musictest.mp3"))



HashMap<String,Bitmap> cache = new HashMap<String,Bitmap>();
public  Bitmap getCoverpicture(String path) {
    if(cache.containsKey(path)){ return cache.get(path);
    }else{
        Bitmap bitmap = coverpicture(path);
        cache.put(path,bitmap);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

It had some syntax errors